# how can i show salary in sql server with currency data like 2000$ or 2000£,and then sum,

Tags: sql-server-2008, currency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using currency $ format with sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883865/using-currency-format-with-sql-server)

In Microsoft Sql server I wan to create a table with column like salary
but for international company ,for example we have many worker **which their salary with dollors and some with euro,or some with pound**,so I want to input in salary 2000$ or 2000e,or 2000 £, and do aggregate like sum ,or count,but in design when I choose money for this column,I can not write $ or £,and then sum? how can **I show  salary whit currency**   like 2000 in **dollors** for person1 ,and 2000**£** for person2 , and then sum all deposit on **£** or sum all deposit or **expenditure** in **$** **dollors**.
How much MY expenditure in dollors,how much my expenditure in euro or pound.

Answer (score 4):

Store the currency units in a separate column. My own preference would be to use the ISO 4217 codes to record this - so that you can distinguish between multiple currencies that use the same symbol, such as US and Australian dollars (USD and AUD).

Any formatting you require (e.g. to produce `$2000.00`) ought then to be done at the front-end, rather than in the database.